# How do I calculate the percentage of a stock portfolio that has been rolled, in R?

Tags: r

I am doing stock portfolio analysis and I want to test the percentage of the portfolio that is rolled between specific dates.

For example: If I have 3 stocks in the portfolio in the first quarter of 2020 that are called "A, B, C", and the following quarter I have three stocks "A, B, D". Then 33% of my portfolio has been rolled between the two dates. The names of my stocks are CUSIP codes, which is an identifier for US stocks. A reproduceable example is:

```
cusip <- c("A1","A2","A3","A1","A2","B1","A1", "C1","C2")
Datecode <- c("201912","201912","201912","202003","202003","202003","202006","202006","202006")
Stocktable <- data_frame(cusip,Datecode)
```

I wish to add the percentage change between each DateCode to a new table that contains summary statistics for my portfolio.

I am sure that this is possible in some way, but I have spent hours trying to do so without getting it right. I am hoping that this community can help!

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: My desired output is a table with two columns (DateCode and PercentChange), And one row for each Datecode, and the percentage change  since previous quarter

Comment: Do you mean to say that since 2 out of 3 were same in each quarter, means that 33% have been changed??

Comment: Yes exactly. And In my reproducable example there has been a 33% change between the first two quarters and a 66% change between the next two quarters. My problem is that I have a dataset with 30+ stock positions for each quarter, so it is not that easy to calculate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

Stocktable %>%
  group_by(Datecode) %>%
  summarise(cusip = list(cusip)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(lag_cusip = lag(cusip)) %>%
  transmute(Datecode,
            percentchange = map2_dbl(cusip, lag_cusip, 
                          ~length(setdiff(.x, .y))/length(.x)) * 100)

#  Datecode percentchange
#  <chr>            <dbl>
#1 201912           100  
#2 202003            33.3
#3 202006            66.7
```

This assumes that your data is sorted according to quarters. It finds out number of new stocks in this quarter compared to previous one and divides with the total stocks of this quarter.

Comment: Nice strategy indeed, as always

Answer (score 3):

You can use `table` and then `apply` with `diff` and `rowSums` to geht the changes.

```
x <- table(Stocktable)
rowSums(apply(x, 1, diff) == 1) / colSums(x[,-ncol(x)]) * 100
#  202003   202006 
#33.33333 66.66667
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly long approach, but will work

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Stocktable %>% mutate(d = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Datecode, names_from = cusip, values_from = d, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(d = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>%
  mutate(across(-c(Datecode, d), ~ lag(., default = NA)*.)) %>%
  mutate(d2 = rowSums(across(-c(Datecode, d)))) %>%
  group_by(Datecode) %>%
  summarise(perc = paste(round(100*(1 - d2/d),2), "%"))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Datecode perc   
* <chr>    <chr>  
1 201912   NA %   
2 202003   33.33 %
3 202006   66.67 %
```

Or more logically, first row should have `0% difference`

```
Stocktable %>% mutate(d = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Datecode, names_from = cusip, values_from = d, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(d = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>%
  mutate(across(-c(Datecode, d), ~ lag(., default = 1)*.)) %>%
  mutate(d2 = rowSums(across(-c(Datecode, d)))) %>%
  group_by(Datecode) %>%
  summarise(perc = paste0(round(100*(1 - d2/d),2), "%"))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Datecode perc  
* <chr>    <chr> 
1 201912   0%    
2 202003   33.33%
3 202006   66.67%
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort AnilGoyal, this is a creative way of solving it